# Why would a POST request using curl work, but not when using Python's requests library

Tags: python, http, github, curl, post

I can send a curl request to upload a release asset file on Github and it works fine:

```bash
$ curl -v -X POST -H "Accept: application/vnd.github+json" -H "Authorization: Bearer <token>" -H "X-GitHub-Api-Version: 2022-11-28" -H "Content-Type: application/octet-stream" https://uploads.github.com/repos/Vuizur/tatoeba-to-anki/releases/93670877/assets?name=test8.apkg --data-binary "@spa_eng.apkg"
Note: Unnecessary use of -X or --request, POST is already inferred.
*   Trying 140.82.121.13:443...
* Connected to uploads.github.com (140.82.121.13) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN: offers h2
* ALPN: offers http/1.1
*  CAfile: C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt
*  CApath: none
* [CONN-0-0][CF-SSL] TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* [CONN-0-0][CF-SSL] TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* [CONN-0-0][CF-SSL] TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Encrypted Extensions (8):
* [CONN-0-0][CF-SSL] TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* [CONN-0-0][CF-SSL] TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, CERT verify (15):
* [CONN-0-0][CF-SSL] TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* [CONN-0-0][CF-SSL] TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS change cipher, Change cipher spec (1):
* [CONN-0-0][CF-SSL] TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSL connection using TLSv1.3 / TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
* ALPN: server accepted h2
* Server certificate:
*  subject: C=US; ST=California; L=San Francisco; O=GitHub, Inc.; CN=*.github.com
*  start date: Jul 21 00:00:00 2022 GMT
*  expire date: Jul 21 23:59:59 2023 GMT
*  subjectAltName: host "uploads.github.com" matched cert's "*.github.com"
*  issuer: C=US; O=DigiCert Inc; CN=DigiCert TLS RSA SHA256 2020 CA1
*  SSL certificate verify ok.
* Using HTTP2, server supports multiplexing
* Copying HTTP/2 data in stream buffer to connection buffer after upgrade: len=0
* h2h3 [:method: POST]
* h2h3 [:path: /repos/Vuizur/tatoeba-to-anki/releases/93670877/assets?name=test8.apkg]
* h2h3 [:scheme: https]
* h2h3 [:authority: uploads.github.com]
* h2h3 [user-agent: curl/7.87.0]
* h2h3 [accept: application/vnd.github+json]
* h2h3 [authorization: Bearer <token>]
* h2h3 [x-github-api-version: 2022-11-28]
* h2h3 [content-type: application/octet-stream]
* h2h3 [content-length: 141403969]
* Using Stream ID: 1 (easy handle 0x25092fa21e0)
> POST /repos/Vuizur/tatoeba-to-anki/releases/93670877/assets?name=test8.apkg HTTP/2
> Host: uploads.github.com
> user-agent: curl/7.87.0
> accept: application/vnd.github+json
> authorization: Bearer <token>
> x-github-api-version: 2022-11-28
> content-type: application/octet-stream
> content-length: 141403969
>
* [CONN-0-0][CF-SSL] TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Newsession Ticket (4):
* [CONN-0-0][CF-SSL] TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Newsession Ticket (4):
* old SSL session ID is stale, removing
* We are completely uploaded and fine
< HTTP/2 201 
< cache-control: no-cache
< content-security-policy: default-src 'none'
< content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8
< etag: W/"203d3f7a98f51759f96c496a467a4980cd4be65469e790005b7701b7938b6d84"
< last-modified: Tue, 28 Feb 2023 15:06:31 GMT
< strict-transport-security: max-age=31557600
< vary: Accept, Authorization, Cookie, X-GitHub-OTP
< x-content-type-options: nosniff
< x-frame-options: deny
< x-github-media-type: github.v3; format=json
< x-xss-protection: 1; mode=block
< date: Tue, 28 Feb 2023 15:06:31 GMT
< x-github-request-id: 0DD4:53A7:8A354:90660:63FE17A9
<
{"url":"https://api.github.com/repos/Vuizur/tatoeba-to-anki/releases/assets/97462199","id":97462199,"node_id":"RA_kwDOHa9_8c4Fzye3","name":"test8.apkg","label":"","uploader":{"login":"Vuizur","id":29223849,"node_id":"MDQ6VXNlcjI5MjIzODQ5","avatar_url":"https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/29223849?v=4","gravatar_id":"","url":"https://api.github.com/users/Vuizur","html_url":"https://github.com/Vuizur","followers_url":"https://api.github.com/users/Vuizur/followers","following_url":"https://api.github.com/users/Vuizur/following{/other_user}","gists_url":"https://api.github.com/users/Vuizur/gists{/gist_id}","starred_url":"https://api.github.com/users/Vuizur/starred{/owner}{/repo}","subscriptions_url":"https://api.github.com/users/Vuizur/subscriptions","organizations_url":"https://api.github.com/users/Vuizur/orgs","repos_url":"https://api.github.com/users/Vuizur/repos","events_url":"https://api.github.com/users/Vuizur/events{/privacy}","received_events_url":"https://api.github.com/users/Vuizur/received_events","type":"User","site_admin":false},"content_type":"application/octet-stream","state":"uploaded","size":141403969,"download_count":0,"created_at":"2023-02-28T15:03:05Z","updated_at":"2023-02-28T15:06:31Z","browser_download_url":"https://github.com/Vuizur/tatoeba-to-anki/releases/download/latest/test8.apkg"}* Connection #0 to host uploads.github.com left intact
```

However, when I do the same in Python requests:

```py
    url = f"https://uploads.github.com/repos/Vuizur/tatoeba-to-anki/releases/{release_id}/assets?name={file}"
    headers = {
        "Accept": "application/vnd.github.v3+json",
        # apkg files are zip files
        "Content-Type": "application/octet-stream",
        # the authorization token
        "Authorization": f"Bearer {os.getenv('GITHUB_TOKEN')}",
    }
    with open(file, "rb") as f:
        #try:
        response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=f, timeout=20) # Not sure about the optimal value, I only know that 0.1 is too small
        print(response)
        #except requests.exceptions.Timeout:
        #    pass
```

Here it also uploads the file well so that I can see it online, but I get the following timeout, preventing me from seeing if the file was uploaded correctly or not (in the case of a strange network error):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Programs\tatoeba-to-anki\.venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 449, in _make_request
    six.raise_from(e, None)
  File "<string>", line 3, in raise_from
  File "C:\Programs\tatoeba-to-anki\.venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 444, in _make_request
    httplib_response = conn.getresponse()
  File "C:\Users\hanne\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\http\client.py", line 1374, in getresponse
    response.begin()
  File "C:\Users\hanne\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\http\client.py", line 318, in begin
    version, status, reason = self._read_status()
  File "C:\Users\hanne\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\http\client.py", line 279, in _read_status
    line = str(self.fp.readline(_MAXLINE + 1), "iso-8859-1")
  File "C:\Users\hanne\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\socket.py", line 705, in readinto
    return self._sock.recv_into(b)
  File "C:\Users\hanne\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\ssl.py", line 1274, in recv_into
    return self.read(nbytes, buffer)
  File "C:\Users\hanne\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\ssl.py", line 1130, in read
    return self._sslobj.read(len, buffer)
TimeoutError: The read operation timed out

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Programs\tatoeba-to-anki\.venv\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 489, in send
    resp = conn.urlopen(
  File "C:\Programs\tatoeba-to-anki\.venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 787, in urlopen
    retries = retries.increment(
  File "C:\Programs\tatoeba-to-anki\.venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\retry.py", line 550, in increment
    raise six.reraise(type(error), error, _stacktrace)
  File "C:\Programs\tatoeba-to-anki\.venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\packages\six.py", line 770, in reraise
    raise value
  File "C:\Programs\tatoeba-to-anki\.venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 703, in urlopen
    httplib_response = self._make_request(
  File "C:\Programs\tatoeba-to-anki\.venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 451, in _make_request
    self._raise_timeout(err=e, url=url, timeout_value=read_timeout)
  File "C:\Programs\tatoeba-to-anki\.venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 340, in _raise_timeout
    raise ReadTimeoutError(
urllib3.exceptions.ReadTimeoutError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='uploads.github.com', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=2)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Programs\tatoeba-to-anki\tatoeba_to_anki\upload_to_release.py", line 62, in <module>
    response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=f, timeout=2) # Not sure about the optimal value, I only know that 0.1 is too small
  File "C:\Programs\tatoeba-to-anki\.venv\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 115, in post
    return request("post", url, data=data, json=json, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Programs\tatoeba-to-anki\.venv\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 59, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Programs\tatoeba-to-anki\.venv\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 587, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "C:\Programs\tatoeba-to-anki\.venv\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 701, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Programs\tatoeba-to-anki\.venv\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 578, in send
    raise ReadTimeout(e, request=request)
```

If I don't set a timeout, the Python code hangs forever. So hitting the timeout is actually what (in almost all cases) only happens after the download has successfully finished.

However, this only occurs with files over a certain size, something like 100 MB. (But also every time, so it is not caused by an unreliable connection.) (Note that it uploads the file correctly every time, the only thing that changes is that it hits the timeout after the correct upload instead of printing the 201 response).

Edit: I also managed to replicate the same behaviour (including the size dependent stuff) in [octokit](https://github.com/octokit/octokit.js/discussions/2402)

For files unter (approximately) 100 MB the code simply prints this (<Response [201]), :

```
Uploading ara_eng.apkg
<Response [201]>
```

Curl always gets the correct 201 response, independent of file size. What could be a reason for this?

(Windows 11, Python 3.10, Curl with Git Bash)

Comment: The reason is quite directly said in the traceback: timeout on read (because it waits for upload to complete). Set longer timeout.

Comment: You know [Github blocks uploads over 100MB](https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/working-with-files/managing-large-files/about-large-files-on-github), right? A repo isn't "arbitrary free storage", if you need to store huge files there's [Git Large File Storage](https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/working-with-files/managing-large-files/about-git-large-file-storage).

Comment: Not sure it matters, but your headers are slightly different

Comment: @freakish If I don't set a timeout, the Python code hangs forever. So hitting the timeout is actually what (in almost all cases) only happens after the download has successfully finished.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans This only applies to Git repositories, but not to releases. Uploading the files works, the problem is only that requests can't seem to get the 201 response.

Comment: Your "this only occurs with files over a certain size, something like 100 MB" suggests otherwise, though. But you know who would be the _perfect_ folks to ask? Github support (especially if you can't find anything about this in the docs, ask them to amend the docs, so that everyone else can find that information in the future, too). Even if you post to SO as your last resort, don't forget to reach out to the people who are actually the most qualified to answer a question through their official channels.

Comment: @JonSG I added the Github API version header to the requests version, it doesn't seem to change anything though.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans The problem is that it works flawlessly with curl, so Github support thinks it is a bug with requests/PyGithub/octokit, which all have the same error (hanging/throwing an exception instead of getting the 201).  So I thought some HTTP specialists might have a hunch.

Comment: You really want to mention you already talked to github support, and what they said, in your post. That's pretty _essential information_, not something to casually mention several comments deep =)

Comment: I see your point, in the conversation I had with support there was no insider info or authorative comments or anything else not in the OP, so I did not include it. But I did not know if I should close the ticket and apologize for my stupid question (as it works in curl) or if they are actually reasons to believe the API is broken (as it is buggy in both TS and Py libraries), so I asked here.